# Find flux of wall of aluminium pipe?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am strugling to find flux in wall of aluminium tube. Length of tube is $l$. Wire goes through the tube having current $I$.

[image]

Result of the problem in book is:

$
\phi = \mu * \frac{Il}{2\pi} * ln(\frac{R_2}{R_1})
$

I have tried to solve problem like this:

$$
B = \mu * \frac{I}{2\pi r}
$$

So the flux is equal to:

$$
\phi = \int_s Bds
$$

What is $ds$ for this problem?
If we set $ds = ldr$

We get integral like this:

$$
\phi = \int_{R_1}^{R_2} \mu * \frac{Il}{2\pi} \frac{1}{r} dr
$$

Which equals to result from the book. But I am thinking that $ds = ldr$ doesn't make sense. So how to solve this problem?

Comment: Replying to the statement that this question is off-topic. Sure it is a question about specific physics concept: **magnetic flux**. As much of effort thing I am sure I have shown that I have tried to solve this problem but where I have stuck is visualising and choosing correct elementary surface ds. I have tried to solve it and needed little guidance of direction where should I look. So I am thinking that this question is not off-topic, but that is my personal opinion. And I am thinking that seeing completed problems step by step is great way to learn and understand how to solve problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You chose the correct integration to do.

[image]